# Dynamically Generate WinForms TreeView from Assembly

Tags: c#, treeview, nodes, .net-assembly

I've almost got it, but I am having a hard time with doing the last part gracefully.  This answer was update based on the answer submitted by Jeremy Thompson. This is what I have so far:

```
public void SetupTree()
{
    var types = Assembly.Load("Data").GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsPublic && t.IsClass);

    if (types.Count() > 0)
    {
        if (treeView_left.Nodes.Count == 0)
        {
            treeView_left.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Structure Data"));
            treeView_left.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(types.First().GetHashCode().ToString(), types.First().Name);
        }

        foreach (Type type in types)
        {
            BuildTree(types, type, treeView_left.Nodes[0].Nodes[0]);
        }
    }

    treeView_left.Refresh();
}

private void BuildTree(IEnumerable<Type> types, Type type, TreeNode parentNode)
{
    var tempNodes = treeView_left.Nodes.Find(type.BaseType.GetHashCode().ToString(), true);
    if (tempNodes.Count() > 0)
    {
        parentNode = tempNodes[0];
        if (tempNodes.Count() != 1)
        {
            //TODO: warning
        }
    }

    if (parentNode != null)
    {
        if (treeView_left.Nodes.Find(type.GetHashCode().ToString(), true).Count() == 0)
        {
            parentNode.Nodes.Add(type.GetHashCode().ToString(), type.Name);
        }

        foreach (Type t in types.Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(type)))
        {
            BuildTree(types, t, parentNode.Nodes[type.GetHashCode().ToString()]);
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the result I am looking for, but I suspect I am doing some of this the hardway. If anyone could point out a cleaner method for the last part I would appriciate it.

Comment: Your method needs to be recursive.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out the best place for something like that. I either end stepping outside of the generic nature that I want this method to use or it doesn't place everything.

Comment: You need an AddNode method that takes an existing node as a parameter.  It checks the node it's on.  If it's the correct node to insert at, it adds the new node there (on the appropriate left or right side) and exits.  If it's not the correct node, you traverse down the correct side of the tree and call AddNode again, using the new node as the parameter.

Comment: Thanks Robert for the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this yet, but notice the Recursive call `LoadAllChildren` calls itself.

```
public void SetupTree()
{
    Assembly dataLib = Assembly.Load("Data");
    TreeNode theTree = new TreeNode("Assembly Data");

    foreach (Type type in dataLib.GetTypes())
    {
        LoadAllChildren(dataLib, type, theTree);
    }

    treeView_left.Nodes.Add(theTree);  //Optimisation - bind all nodes in one go rather than adding individually
}

private void LoadAllChildren(Assembly dataLib,Type type, TreeNode parentNode)
{
    if (type.IsPublic && type.IsClass)
    {            
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(type.Name);
        parentNode.Nodes.Add(node);           

        var types = dataLib.GetTypes().Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(type));
        foreach (Type t in types)
        {
            LoadAllChildren(dataLib, t, node);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this is enough to get you over the hurdle, feel free to ask Q's

*I wont respond quickly as my PC is about to get rebuilt:(*

Comment: Thanks Jeremy -- it's almost there, you are actually at one of the same points I was at earlier before posting. It creates the tree -- but each item and it's subs get added to the base of the project.  It needs to stop the chain if it get's added.

Comment: Updated my questions with a version that does the sub-categories correctly. Still want to clean it up though.

Comment: Marking this as the answer, although please note that it adds in too many categories.  Please see the updated question for the completed solution.